# Any way in LWC jest testing to make sure a child component received the right data from the parent?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-jest

I understand the philosophy that Jest is about "black box" testing, where you just observe the effects of the code. So you have limited access to things, and have to rely on observing differences in render HTML, events dispatched, API, etc.

Bu if you have no way to just test if the parent is passing the right data to a child component, then that leaves a big gap in terms of observing effects. And you cant simply test the child component to cover this.  If you happen to also render the values you pass or decorate them with @API, then you can observe them, but that's often not the case.

Any suggestions for how to test this aspect of components' effects in Jest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an example available on [LWC Recipes](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/main/force-app/main/default/lwc/compositionBasics/__tests__/compositionBasics.test.js) which shows how to verify the data passed in child. In this recipe, compositionBasics is parent and contactTile is child lwc component.

Adding a specific piece of code from the jest test:-

```
  it('renders with contact tile properties set', () => {
        const USER_RESULT = 'Amy Taylor';
        const TITLE_RESULT = 'VP of Engineering';

        // Create initial element
        const element = createElement('c-composition-basics', {
            is: CompositionBasics
        });
        document.body.appendChild(element);

        // Select contact tile for public property check
        const contactTileEl =
            element.shadowRoot.querySelector('c-contact-tile');
        expect(contactTileEl.contact.Name).toBe(USER_RESULT);
        expect(contactTileEl.contact.Title).toBe(TITLE_RESULT);
    });
```

In this case, This jest test exist on parent, where parent pass the data to child.This might help you.